# Change JSON output "format" - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

(i'm a bit new in PHP / JSON) i have a PHP page that send me an array of informations to an Android application and i need to change the Json "format" so i can manage it in my Android application.

I tried adding the array to a PHP class but i only get errors.

From this (this is just an example):

```
 [
   {
      "updated_at":"2012-03-02 21:06:01",
      "fetched_at":"2012-03-02 21:28:37.728840",
      "description":null,
      "language":null,
      "title":"JOHN",
      "url":"http://rus.JOHN.JOHN/rss.php",
      "icon_url":null,
      "logo_url":null,
      "id":"4f4791da203d0c2d76000035",
      "modified":"2012-03-02 23:28:58.840076"
   },
   {
      "updated_at":"2012-03-02 14:07:44",
      "fetched_at":"2012-03-02 21:28:37.033108",
      "description":null,
      "language":null,
      "title":"PETER",
      "url":"http://PETER.PETER.lv/rss.php",
      "icon_url":null,
      "logo_url":null,
      "id":"4f476f61203d0c2d89000253",
      "modified":"2012-03-02 23:28:57.928001"
   }
]
```

To this (other example):

```
{"master":[
   {
      "updated_at":"2012-03-02 21:06:01",
      "fetched_at":"2012-03-02 21:28:37.728840",
      "description":null,
      "language":null,
      "title":"JOHN",
      "url":"http://rus.JOHN.JOHN/rss.php",
      "icon_url":null,
      "logo_url":null,
      "id":"4f4791da203d0c2d76000035",
      "modified":"2012-03-02 23:28:58.840076"
   },
   {
      "updated_at":"2012-03-02 14:07:44",
      "fetched_at":"2012-03-02 21:28:37.033108",
      "description":null,
      "language":null,
      "title":"PETER",
      "url":"http://PETER.PETER.lv/rss.php",
      "icon_url":null,
      "logo_url":null,
      "id":"4f476f61203d0c2d89000253",
      "modified":"2012-03-02 23:28:57.928001"
   }
]
}
```

My PHP page that create the JSON array:

```
<?php

    class card{

        public $id = 0;
        public $name = "";
        public $value = 0;
        public $imgpath = "";
        public $rarity = "";
        public $litness = 0;
        public $dankness = 0;
        public $expansion = "";


    }

    $b= array();

    $connessione = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");

    $query = "insert_query_here";

    $risultato = mysqli_query($connessione, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($risultato)){

    $card = new card();
    $card->id = $row['id_card'];
    $card->name = $row['name'];
    $card->value = $row['value'];
    $card->imgpath = $row['imgpath'];
    $card->rarity = $row['name_rarity'];
    $card->litness = $row['litness'];
    $card->dankness = $row['dankness'];
    $card->expansion = $row['expansion_name'];

    $b[] = $card;

    }

    $out = array_values($b);
    print json_encode($out);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$out = ['master' => array_values($b)];
print json_encode($out);
```

This will add the key `master` in the main array, and the rest will be nested in it.